# How to pass the entire body of a HTTP Post as a single string to WebAPI

Tags: http-post, asp.net-web-api

I have a "lookup" WebAPI service that returns lookup table data like Salutations (Mr Mrs etc) and some that are a lot longer (e.g. business types).

To save myself trouble populating a lookup table manually I added a HttpPost method, assuming I could simply pass a *line delimited* set of data in the body using Fiddler2. This way I could just paste lists of data into fiddler and add all my lookups in seconds:

```
    // post api/lookup/lookupName
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveNewLookups([FromUri(Name="id")] string lookupName, [FromBody]string body)
```

But now matter what I tried for the content type, the body parameter is always null when the method is hit.

I got around it by using the following code to access the raw body text, but it would be nice to get the parameterized version working:

```
string body = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I do not want to use a JSON, or other, format for the data as that would defeat the purpose of using simple text lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put `'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` in the request header and then put your string content into fiddler preceded by an equals (=) sign. For example:

```
=datavalue1
datavalue2
```

You should receive your data values in the controller as:

```
datavalue1\r\ndatavalue2
```

Comment: Bingo. I had tried each of those two things separately, but must have missed putting them together :) Cheers

Comment: WebApi has problems. This kind of finagling wastes hours upon hours of time, and then you have to remember the special way they want stuff when you come back and remember it again. Worse, the sender in has to take part in this finagling. There is absolutely no good reason that this simple operation (read the stupid body into a simple string!) should require a form-url-encoded content type, or as in Darrel's response, a special formatter. I'm excited about the upcoming merge of MVC and WepApi, but I'm scared they may bring in this nastiness to MVC. Scary.

Comment: Consider, I'm receiving content from iOS and Android devices. To use *either* of these routes (Susiak or Miller's), I would have to coordinate with all senders, from obviously different app code bases (iOS and Android), that they either form-url-encode this simple body message (when it is just a simple string!, it is not a form), or, that they set text/plain content-type header (besides my extra work to do). But there should be no reason to reject this message if a default content-type is used like 'text/html'. It just shouldn't matter, but this state of affairs doesn't provide that choice.

Answer (score 4):

Add a [PlainTextFormatter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/blob/master/src/WebApiContrib/Formatting/PlainTextFormatter.cs) to your list of formatters and set the content-type to `text/plain`

Comment: Handy link, but Jonny S' answer works and requires no special code. Thanks

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. It worked like a charm. Staggering that WebApi doesn't have this out of the box. For others: put his code (this PlainTextFormatter class) somewhere in your solution, then register it like this:    `config.Formatters.Add(new PlainTextFormatter());` That's it. Now it just works (though your string parameter will still need [FromBody] decoration): `public HttpResponseMessage NewComment(int postId, int orgId, [FromBody] string body) ...`